# Dynamically execute function in Python

Tags: python

I have a set of functions in a class

```
class uloader:
    @staticmethod
    def describe(o1):
```

At run-time I get to know the name of the function I want to execute dynamically and the parameter, too. eg. describe(porsche), or dyn_fun = describe(porsche).
How would I execute this - should I code eval(dyn_fun)? I need the output from describe() again passed to a html page

Comment: `gettatr(uloader, 'describe')(globals()['porche'])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get attribute from an object:

```
# method_name = 'describe'
method = getattr(uloader, method_name)
method(porsche)
```